# Faster way of iterating through adjacency list?

Tags: java, graph, iteration, adjacency-list

I'm trying to find the longest length of a path in a graph, so I map out the paths from each starting node and get the longest. To do this, I have to constantly iterate through my adjacency list and mark each node as not visited to start the process over, and those few lines of code are slowing my program down immensely.

```
for (int j=0; j < V; j++) {
    adj[j].isVisited = false;
}
```

Is there a faster way to mark all of the nodes in my adjacency list as not visited?

Comment: Java is an interpreted language.  Therefore it is slow.  A compiled language will be faster. C++17 has special syntax to set all the values of a vector to a constant.  It is blazingly fast!  A few miiliseconds  to set a million element vector.

Comment: Not memory efficient, but you could change `isVisited` from a `bool` to a `Set<UUID>`, and  use a new UUID on each call to find a path.  That would allow multiple paths to be determined in parallel.

Comment: @AndrewS I would think that inserting into a set would be a LOT slower than updating an indexed element of a vector.  ( If using ||el computation, you can use a thread specific vector with no performance hit. )